# jquery load not loading in IE6

Tags: jquery, load, internet-explorer-6

I got a simple jquery script workin on all but IE

```
    j('.slide').click(function(){
        j('#content').load('/menu.php');
        return false;
    });
```

Here's the url http://identitykit.gotdns.org/ 
it's valid xhtml and all other similar questions don't answer my problem.

menu.php starts with

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a DOCUMENT READY tag

Comment: it is in the j(document).ready(function(){}); or what do you mean by "DOCUMENT READY tag"?

Answer (score 1):

It was **my IE6 security settings** for the ***internet zone*** disabling **active X**. This possibility was not addressed in other similar questions and could have been solved if someone told me that it **works in their IE6 browsers**.
Cheers to all

Answer (score 0):

You've got all your `<script>` content in your `<body>`. Have you tried moving it into the `<head>`? (Edit: I see the answer to that is yes).

How about switching from `(document).ready()` to `(window).load()`? With IE, anything's worth a try.

Comment: yes, it was first in my head, wasn't working up their either, moving it to the end was me trying to solve this issue, also it's a recommendation for load performance

Comment: IE. Foiled again. Never fails to fail.